# pcl for laser sensor

Tags: slam, navigation, mapping, laser, scan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm really confused. I want to make a map of the environment by using laser scans. I know I have to use pcl, but I cannot understand what is the use of pcl does it store all the scan over a period of time and hence i can plot it ? Please help. I tried reading PCL online, didn’t really help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195503/pcl-for-laser-sensor/) by [aniket](https://answers.ros.org/users/18764/aniket/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2014-10-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why don't you use [gmapping](http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping) or [hector_mapping](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_mapping)?

---

Originally posted by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) with karma: 651 on 2014-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aniket](https://answers.ros.org/users/18764/aniket/) on 2014-10-22**:
I will look into both of them. Which do feel is better for laser mapping ? and can you give me a small description on how they work ? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

PCL (point cloud library) contains various methods to work with point clouds. So it is not a 3D laser mapping, but could be used to implement one. If you want to use a 2D mapping, you may be better off with a ready-to-use mapping, as ROSCMBOT suggested.

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) with karma: 1658 on 2014-10-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aniket](https://answers.ros.org/users/18764/aniket/) on 2014-10-22**:
I will look into roscmbot. I was thinking of starting from scratch. But I guess I can start with a ready-to-use mapping and then probably go about making it from scratch. Thank Yoiu.